# Looking for ideas for an automatic thread feeder

Tags: switches, thread

I need to feed a very fine nylon thread in a process by controlling a spool motor. There is not enough pull on the thread from the process to have the thread activate a push-button, even with a 1"-long lever on the button. Anyways ideally there should be no tension on the thread, so I guess you can say I want "slack management".

The system is controlled with an MCU but it doesn't really matter, all I want is a signal when the thread begins to tension to activate the feed motor for a few seconds (it is a 1/3 RPM 120VAC synchonous motor controlled by a SSR relay). I am not very well versed in mecanical things, perhaps there is a mecanical solution to this. I checked sewing machine-type thread tension regulator principles but these rely on a strong pull from the needle mechanism to regulate via springs, as I stated earlier the process can't and shouldn't pull on the thread.

As far as electrical detection goes, I am too newbie to know many solutions. I was thinking perhaps when the thread is slack it could rest on a plane with two contacts, shunting the gate of a mosfet to ground in a (very) high impedance input circuit, kind of like a "touch button" circuit. I'm not sure the thread has enough conductivity for this, I'll go now and check that, but perhaps someone can already tell me that can or can't work.

Of course all solution suggestions are welcome.
Thanks in advance,
J.

Comment: Hard to visualise, but could do with a diagram and an idea of whether expensive and complicated solutions are ok

Comment: What are you feeding the thread into?

Comment: The thread is fed into a succion tube - there isn't enough succion to provide much pull. There is no receiving spool.

Comment: @Joe So all of the tension available on the string comes from a suction tube (and it's not much?) How do you manage *tension control*, exactly? What are the details of the closed loop? What do you modify, assuming you can detect slack in the tension?

Comment: @jonk There is no tension control as the tension is not a critical factor. The succion is from a small vacuum pump; it can pick a bit of loose thread but can't unspool the thread on its own. That is why I need a spool motor to provide a bit of slack on the thread line. If the spool motor runs continuously then loose thread accumulates. I guess I could just drive the motor at intervals but the duty cycle would need to be variable to account for the spool diameter reducing as it is emptying.

Comment: @Joe I suppose this may be my fault in reading your writing then. You wrote, *"I want 'slack management'"*, and I interpreted that as "tension control." Since I remain confused lacking a clear diagram of the situation, and others appear to have it well under control in their minds, I'll back off and leave it to those who grasp this question better than I do.

Comment: this question should really be asked at https://engineering.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

In industry this would be referred to as a dancer-controlled unwind system.

[image]

*Figure 1. A label unwind stand with dancer-controlled motor. Image source: [AZCO](https://www.azcocorp.com/ud-dancerunwind-stand-rewind-stand.html).*

A longer dancer arm will give you more torque for a given thread tension. [This one](https://ie.farnell.com/itw-switches/19n503l63/microswitch-v4-pcb-long-lever/dp/624720), for example, has a long lever and a maximum actuation force of 1.5 N (0.15 kg). If this is too much then consider an optical or inductive proximity switch to give contactless monitoring of the dancer position.

For engineering you need numbers. Get a digital kitchen scales or similar, put an object on it, tare the scales and pull the thread down both sides of the object with the maximum tension your want. Record the measurement in kg. Multiply by 10 (9.81 m/s/s) to convert to newtons (N). Then look at the switch specifications and see if it is sensitive enough.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I learnt a lot today. The push-button with lever I mentioned in my original question is the same microswitch type as the one you linked, except it has a smaller lever. I could try to extend the lever and see if it is actuated when the pump pulls on the thread.

Comment: @Joe: See the update on tension measurement.

Answer (score 1):

Strain gauge could be a solution for sensing very low forces:
[image: Strain gauge]
There will be a change of resistance when the wire puts any force on the stain gauge. Resistance is easy to measure. There should be a hole or loop at the tip of the straing gauge and the other end would be fixed. Strain gauges come in many sizes and formats.

Comment: Might also be able to replace the strain gauge with a fiber optic whisker. Won't measure force but will indicate disturbance.

Comment: Yea, I think the second best option would be by some form of an optical measurement. Something as simple a "slot photointerrupter" such as: https://media.digikey.com/Photos/Omron%20Elect%20Photos/MFG_EE-SX4162-P2.jpg

Comment: A strain gauge seems a good solution - I'm reading on them as I'm not familiar with those. I believe the succion from the vacuum pump would be enough pull for a precision strain gauge. They are cheap enough and could be easily interfaced with the on-chip precision analog comparator. I might flag that as solution after investigating both strain gauges and slot photointerrupters. Thanks gents!